# TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters when doing npm whoami and npm install

Tags: npm, npm-install

Here's the error message my colleague gets when he does `npm whoami`:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/Users/dariusgatlin/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/node" "/Users/dariusgatlin/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/npm" "whoami"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8

npm ERR! The header content contains invalid characters
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/dariusgatlin/WebstormProjects/account-service/npm-debug.log
```

`npm login` works, but `npm install` produces the same error message

Here is the npm-debug log

```
17 http request GET https://registry.npmjs.org/-/whoami
18 verbose stack TypeError: The header content contains invalid characters
18 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:351:13)
18 verbose stack     at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:79:14)
18 verbose stack     at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
18 verbose stack     at Object.socket.once.exports.request (https.js:182:15)
18 verbose stack     at Request.start (/Users/dariusgatlin/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:753:32)
18 verbose stack     at Request.end (/Users/dariusgatlin/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1418:10)
18 verbose stack     at end (/Users/dariusgatlin/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:580:14)
18 verbose stack     at Immediate._onImmediate (/Users/dariusgatlin/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:594:7)
18 verbose stack     at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
19 verbose cwd /Users/dariusgatlin/WebstormProjects/account-service
20 error Darwin 14.5.0
21 error argv "/Users/dariusgatlin/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/node" "/Users/dariusgatlin/.nvm/versions/node/v4.4.7/bin/npm" "whoami"
22 error node v4.4.7
23 error npm  v2.15.8
24 error The header content contains invalid characters
25 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
25 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
26 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Debugging steps tried include:

- restart machine
- Reinstall Node version
- try several different Node versions, including old ones and new ones

Possibly-related note about the error: http://www.alexkras.com/typeerror-the-header-content-contains-invalid-characters/

Answer (score 1):

My advice to you would be to check out your registry values using `open ~/.npmrc`.

I had this same issue for a few days myself.  It turns out that my values inside of my `~/.npmrc` file were incorrect.  Edit your values, clear your npm cache and node_modules folders, and run npm install again.

Originally:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@company:registry=https://your-repo-key-address/dev/registry/
//your-repo-key-address/dev/registry/:_authToken="abc"
```

Fix:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@company:registry=https://your-repo-key-address/dev/registry/
//your-repo-value-address/dev/registry/:_authToken="abc"
```

These lines are npm's default registry address, your company's private registry address, and the value to be passed to the key address, respectively.
I figured this out by working closely with the registry team and having them forward me the registry addresses.

I hope this helps!